# How to create multiline ChoiceChip within Row with MainAxisSize.min in flutter?

Tags: flutter, layout

I am trying the following code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(
    home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
      body: HomePage(),
    )),
  ));
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const data = [
      'long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long ',
      'short'
    ];
    return Wrap(
        children: List<Widget>.generate(
            2,
            (i) => ChoiceChip(
                  selected: false,
                  label: Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      const Icon(Icons.abc),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Text(
                          data[i],
                          softWrap: true,
                          maxLines: 10,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )));
  }
}
```

I need to show the both `ChoiceChips` but the second should take minimum space.

Now the second `ChoiceChip` takes a full screen width. If I remove `Expanded` then the first `ChoiceChip` shows one line only.

What should I do?